# DNS query through squid?

Tags: network, malware, dns, proxy

My IDS picked up our squid proxy server doing a dynamic DNS request.  I wasn't aware squid passed DNS requests from the client to the internal DNS server.  Is this possible?

Snort Alert:

```
ET POLICY DYNAMIC_DNS .dyndns.org DNS Lookup - Possible Malware
```

Answer (score 1):

A Socks 5 compatible proxy support DNS look-ups,  and squid supports the sock 5 protocol.  On a side note,  TOR can make use of Sock 5 for their own DNS .onion domains.  This is probably a false positive on behalf of snort,  I don't see how this is a security issue.

Comment: Is there a log I could verify that with?

Comment: It is a dyn dns query for chosenones.dyndns.org.  That's what's in the payload.  Dynamic dns queries are a security issue.  I'm trying to find the machine that made the original request.  All snort gave me was the proxy address.